# Django: Custom permissions for group-based model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django and StackOverflow so please be a bit chill with me! I will update the code and everything as per requests.

I'm currently working on a system where students can join groups called Societies. These Societies have a ManyToManyField relationship with Users. I have been trying to think of a way to build a system where within each Society, there are Leaders and general members. Leaders can promote members to be fellow leaders, delete posts in the society, or even kick members of the society.

I would love some guidance in the right direction on how to structure (or re-structure!) my code. Specifically, I would like to know how to incorporate a "Leader" group of users with custom permissions like the one described above, that I can then use in my templates. Thank you!

```
class Society(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name=("Members"))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class SocPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    society = models.ForeignKey(Society, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'society_id':self.society.id, 'pk':self.pk})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use a [through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```py
class SocietyMembership(models.Model)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='society_membership')
    society = models.ForeignKey('Society')
    is_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Society(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        verbose_name=("Members"),
        related_name='societies',
        through=SocietyMembership
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

This avoids extra queries injected by `ContentTypes` and the need to create one leader group per society in order to separate permissions from one group to the next.

---

Update:

Model update:

```py
class Society(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        verbose_name=_("Members"),
        related_name="societies",
        through=SocietyMembership,
    )

    @property
    def leaders(self):
        return self.memberships.filter(is_leader=True)

    def user_is_leader(self, user: User):
        return self.memberships.filter(is_leader=True, member=user).exists()

    def is_member(self, user: User):
        return self.members.filter(pk=user.id).exists()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    def enroll(self, user: User, as_leader: bool = False):
        # Django >= 2.2, which it should be in July 2020
        self.members.add(user, through_defaults={"is_leader": as_leader})

    def promote(self, user: User) -> bool:
        try:
            membership = self.memberships.get(member=user)
        except SocietyMembership.DoesNotExist:
            return False

        membership.is_leader = True
        membership.save()
        return True

    def kick(self, user: User):
        self.memberships.filter(member=user).delete()
```

Example of a views with permission check:

```py
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin
from . import models


class SocietyList(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Society
    template_name = "main/society-list.html"
    context_object_name = "societies"


class SocietyDetail(UserPassesTestMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Society
    template_name = "main/society-detail.html"
    context_object_name = "society"

    def test_func(self):
        # self.object will be an instance of Society
        if not hasattr(self, "object"):
            setattr(self, "object", self.get_object())
        return self.object.is_member(self.request.user)
```

Comment: Hi Melvyn, thank you for your answer! I had a question or two. This seems like a great approach. However, 1) how would I allow specific elements on a template only to be visible to leaders and 2) how would I structure the function to be passed into user_passes_test to match the society being passed into the view as a context? Since different societies have different leaders, I was just trying to picture how I would build the function.

Comment: Good point - the decorator won't have context. You'd have to use CBV mixins and get current society via `self.kwargs` or `self.request.POST/GET`, so [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) would be able to handle it.

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to get some clarification on the through_field attribute? I have gotten some errors and after some quick researching, it seems to be because I did not define the fields. Must I define all three fields in SocietyMembership or just the member and society?

Comment: It's past 3am here, but the basics for checking if a user is a leader is to write a template tag you can pass a user object and society to. I'll check back after sleep if you're still stuck :)

Comment: Rest well! I had an error as follows: ValueError: Cannot alter field societies.Society.members into societies.Society.members - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields). I did a bit of reading and I have been playing around with migrations but my knowledge of migrations is not too vast so I am a bit hesitant about creating too many.

Comment: If this is not live yet, migrations are for your amusement. At the start of an application you often change datamodel through progressing insights about the problem domain. It's not bad to rollback all migrations (`python manage.py migrate <appname> zero` + `rm <appname>/migrations/0*` for all apps) and start anew. The only downside is you have to create the sample data again you were working with. But the primary purpose of migrations is to have changes in database schema without destroying production data and during initial development that doesn't apply.

Comment: I managed to solve everything except with the user_passes_test. However, I will figure it out. Thank you for all the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I played with it a bit today, so here ya go. :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that your additions above were absolutely amazing. Thank you so much Melvyn, you've been incredibly helpful.

Comment: I found this for searching for a similar issue. @Melvyn can you perhaps help me also? :) My issue is similar, but in my case users still can be not present in the system.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66726368/how-should-i-structure-my-database-entities-with-invites-and-recipients-for-e-si

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want your 'leaders' to be an admin, denoted by the 'is_superuser' field in the default django user model. What you described are typical admin activities in Django (and can easily be done in the django admin panel). Create one of these superusers by executing `python manage.py createsuperuser` and then you will have access to the admin panel where you can customize everything you need, and promote more users to admin level. If you are looking for some level of leadership between basic user and admin, you can create users with custom permissions dependent on the `user_permissions` field, denoted by some sort of variable which you add to the django default user model using a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Superusers have way too many privileges (like all of them).

Comment: Which is why I offered an alternative with less permissions. Read the whole answer before responding or downvoting

Comment: Hi figbar, thank you for your answer! I am slightly confused. How would I be able to differentiate these leaders between societies? Users can be leaders in some societies but normal members in others. Just a quick clarification would be great. Thank you so much!