# How should I structure my database entities with invites and recipients for e-signing web app in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, django-rest-framework, relationship

I am interested in implementing the following requirements for my e-signature web application.

1. A user can create a new signing contract. That contract can include multiple users to sign. The contract creator needs to provide **emails** of the recipients. Every recipient will have additional data assigned, like signing details, instructions and etc.
2. However, the invited user can still be **not present in the system**. This is the trickest part.

Right now my following implementation is the following:

1. I create a contract, then check if a user is present in the system by making a filter by email. If the user exists, I create a **many-to-many entity ContractRecipientEvent using *through intermediate* *table* with additional data**, which is assigned to the contract. I create it many-to-many because the same user can be assigned to multiple contracts.
2. If the user is not present I create the Invitation model, set all recipient's specific data, and send an email. Then the user is registered, I run the query of a**ll Invitations records with that email** and create ContractRecipientEvent, by **copying** data from the Invitation model.

What I don't like with my approach are the following things:

1. Many-to-many field. I would like to just use plain Foreign keys for my contract recipients, but I am unsure how should I assign multiple users to the same contract? Perhaps I should create a new model ContractRecipient with the user and contract as foreign keys, but that is a many-to-many field also?
2. I don't like that I need to **copy data from the Invitation model to the ContractRecipientEvent** and only create ContractRecipientEvent after the user is registered, because I need a user entity to create a ContractRecipientEvent, which has a foreign key to the user.
3. The permission structure is difficult to manage. I need to check all the users, who are included in the contract database record, and check if they are assigned to the **contract id, they are using for the signing POST request**.

I am attaching my final JSON code of the contract list. It works, but I would like to have a correct models structure:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 178,
      "is_author": true,
      "title": "ahhzhzh",
      "message_to_all_recipients": null,
      "contract_signing_status": "WAITING_FOR_ME",
      "contract_signing_type": "SIMPLE",
      "contract_signing_date": {
        "start_date": "2010-09-04T14:15:22Z",
        "end_date": "2010-09-04T14:15:22Z"
      },
      "recipients": [
        {
          "message": null,
          "recipient_signing_status": "NOT_SIGNED",
          "recipient_review_status": "NOT_REQUIRED",
          "recipient_action": "SIGN",
          "role": "ADMIN",
          "email": "test2331@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "message": null,
          "recipient_signing_status": "NOT_SIGNED",
          "recipient_review_status": "NOT_REQUIRED",
          "recipient_action": "SIGN",
          "role": "BASE",
          "email": "test2333@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 179,
      "is_author": true,
      "title": "dhhdhd",
      "message_to_all_recipients": null,
      "contract_signing_status": "WAITING_FOR_ME",
      "contract_signing_type": "SIMPLE",
      "contract_signing_date": {
        "start_date": "2010-09-04T14:15:22Z",
        "end_date": "2010-09-04T14:15:22Z"
      },
      "recipients": [
        {
          "message": null,
          "recipient_signing_status": "NOT_SIGNED",
          "recipient_review_status": "NOT_REQUIRED",
          "recipient_action": "SIGN",
          "role": "ADMIN",
          "email": "test123@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "message": null,
          "recipient_signing_status": "NOT_SIGNED",
          "recipient_review_status": "NOT_REQUIRED",
          "recipient_action": "SIGN",
          "role": "BASE",
          "email": "test233@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    },
 
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your aversion to ManyToMany. Can you expand on that a bit? Is it giving you trouble and what would be solved by using "plain foreign keys"?

Comment: Hello, since then I got help from another user. I will use his suggested approach. Do you agree with that? The approach is here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/423672/387517

Comment: It will be better if you share an ERD diagram of your DB or your current models structures, this will make it more clear with fewer words, and keep the description for describing your system flow only

Comment: Yes, I agree about the M2M part. It's a normal pattern in data models, independent of the programming language or framework. They are also not "plain foreign keys", but **two** foreign keys. OneToOneField is a special Foreign Key (one with a unique constraint). About the user though, it's possible to implement a Guest user and create a session for that user. You don't store anything permanent, unless the user indicates they want to register. After all, signing a document should not behind the scene register the person with your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the only difference between a M2M and two ForeignKeys is the through table but let's see if I understand. What if we started with the following models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
  email = models.CharField(...)
  ...

class Contract(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('User', ..., related_name='contracts')
  ...

class Signature(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('User', ..., related_name='signatures')
  contract = models.ForeignKey('User', ..., related_name='signatures')
  is_signed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  ...

class Event(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey('User', ..., related_name='events')
  contract = models.ForeignKey('Contract', ..., related_name='events')
  signature = models.ForeignKey('Signature', ..., related_name='events') 
  message = models.CharField(...)
  ...
```

Now we can do things like:

```py
# get a specific user:
user = User.objects.get(email=<email>)

# get all of the contracts they own:
users_contracts = user.contracts.all() # OR
users_contracts = Contract.objects.filter(user=user)

# get a specific contract:
contract = Contract.objects.get(id=<contract-id>)

# get all the signatures on a contract:
signatures_on_contract = contract.signatures.all() # OR
signatures_on_contract = Signature.objects.filter(contract=contract)

# get all the signatures for a user:
users_signatures = user.signatures.all()

# get all the contracts that the user signed:
users_signed_contracts = Contracts.objects.filter(
  signatures__in = users_signatures,
  signatures__is_signed = True
)

# get all the events on the contract:
events = contract.events.order_by('id')
```

Now our contract json can look something like:

```js
// i.e.: contract with id 7:
{
  'id' : 7,
  'user' : {
    'id' : 2,
    'email' : 'some@email.com'
  },
  'signatures' : [
    {
      'id' : 3,
      'user' : {
        'id' : 2,
        'email' : 'some@email.com'
      },
      'is_signed' : true
    },
    {
      'user' : {
        'id' : 4,
        'email' : 'other@email.com'
      },
      'is_signed' : false
    }
  ],
  'events' : [
    {
      'id' : 6,
      'user' : {
        'id' : 2,
        'email' : 'some@email.com'
      },
      'contract' : {
        'id' : 7
      },
      'signature' : {
        'id' : 3
      },
      'message' : 'signed contract 7'
    }
  ]
}
```

The `Event` model here is perhaps overqualified and doesn't need all the `ForeignKey` relations it has, but this way you can flexibly create your json.

## EDIT

Handling users who need to sign a contract:

```
# a list of emails:
emails = ['email@1.com', 'email@2.com', ...]

for email in emails:

    # get or create a user:
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=email)

    # new user logic:
    if created:
        # set temp password
        # redirect users to change password page before signing a doc (can be done elsewhere)
        ...

    # existing user logic:
    else:
        ...

    # create signatures for each user, and add them to the contract:
    signature = Signature.objects.create(user=user, contract=contract)
    ...
```

## EDIT 2

Here is one example of limiting requests to the `Signature` table based on objects using DRF:

**views.py**

```py
class SignatureViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    # override this method to limit access:
    def get_queryset(self):

        # superusers can access all items:
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.queryset

        # otherwise, users can only access their own signatures:
        else:
            return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks. How should I manage unregistered users? Should I create them with just email, as soon as the contract owner adds them as recipients and when they decide to register I will fill password and other data to the model?

Comment: Yes exactly - you can use `get_or_create` to get or create a user based on their email - then you can add a bit of extra logic for new users. You can also initialize a "temp" password and require new users to change their passwords when they first sign up etc. - See my edits

Comment: Thanks again! One more question regarding permissions. I have a POST request named sign. It signs a document (performs multiple network requests and updates status of recipient to SIGNED). How should I protect access for that method, so that only recipients can access it? Should I just make a basic filter and search for recipients of that contract, if they don't exist return permission invalid? What about using custom django permissions handling?

Comment: There are multiple ways of solving this - probably the best way is to use object level permissions - i.e. only users who have signatures on the contract can send the "sign" POST request - I'll add an example using DRF of what this might look like.

Comment: Oh, I see, by having a separate model for Signature, you can make permissions tied directly to the Signature, instead of to the contract. Just one more thing. If suppose I decide to use M2M ( I have read about it, and this logically required M2M). How should my Event model look like? Should it have a ForeignKey to the Intermediate table between User and Contract model? Or should I put everything to that Event model, including data from the Signature model, like is_signed?

Comment: Also, I am little bit lost, why Event has a Foreign key instead of having OneToOneField?

Comment: Sounds about right - the contract model will have a ForeignKey to a user called `owner` (1 owner per contract, many owned contracts per user) and a M2M relation to `signers` (multiple signers per contract and multiple contracts signed per user) - then, as you say, you may want to move the `is_signed` field to `Event` that is true when a `signer` signs a contract.

Comment: A user can cause multplie events (signed many contracts), a contract can have multiple events (many people signed the contract), a signature may be able to get by with a O2O if there is ever only one event per signature (however I assumed there are multiple steps to "signing " a contract hence FK)

Comment: Thank you! Awarded a bounty! Just one more question, since I will be having signers as M2M and it will be an intermediate table done woth through key in Django model, how should I structure my API? Specifically the sign request. I think about adding it to the /contracts/id/sign endpoint, which would require only JWT bearer token. However, I would then need to update my permission and make it to the Contract? But if I would do that, I would need to query through all signers and check if they contain a JWT of the user, who called /contracts/id/sign? Or perhaps I should create /signers/id/sign?

Comment: Again there are many solutions - the method you suggest would only require one extra SQL command (joining tables) - I suggest you play around with different architectures and see what fits your needs best.

Comment: I managed to implement the flow. One concern occurred to me. By using this method, I can clutter my user's table with too many invited users. This seems like a bad choice. Perhaps I should just use a Foreign key to the SigningUser, which would be a new model with an email in it. How about this?

Comment: Also, what about using this in the following way:
1. I would create a Contract Signer table, which would have an email and contractId as foreign key. Then I would set the email to the provided email. Then I don't need to use a users id for the ContractSigner table. I would query all user's contracts, by querying the ContractSigners table with that user's email. This way I would not clutter my users' table, with unregistered users. Is this much better or am I missing something?
@Daniel

Comment: Sounds fine to me - its up to you how to organize your db - it also should not be too hard to switch between those two structures if you decide to change it down the line.

Comment: Yes, however, I decided to stick with the user's approach. I think it will help, because if I decide to change user's email, I would need to update all records of ContractSigner table. The only drawback with the user's approach is the possibility to clutter users' table. Or perhaps I am overthinking it and the size of the data is not a problem down the road and has solutions?

Comment: one more question. Should I return Events to each user instead of Contracts? Because, if I return Contracts it is a lot harder to add categories for example, or notes for those Contracts for each user individually. If I would make a foreign key of Category model directly to Event it would be easier, right?